# ActiveRecord Join that gets first associated product photo

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, join

I'm using ActiveRecord inside CodeIgniter to interact with a MySQL database.

I have a product table and a product_photo table that stores associated photos for products along with a sort_order for each product_photo.

I am attempting to select the first product photo (lowest sort_order) but can't seem to make it work.

I've boiled it down to selecting the product_photo and joining the product to it (I tried the opposite initially) but I always end up with the first product_photo for the first test product and second product_photo for the second test product.

To simplify further, I tried selecting just the product_photo records, sorting them by product_id and sort_order, and then spitting that out and I still end up with mis-matched results.

Here's my ActiveRecord query:

```
$this->db->select('product_id, url, sort_order')
         ->from('product_photo')
         ->order_by('product_id, sort_order')
         ->group_by('product_id');
```

I'm sure there is a better approach to this, but I haven't found it yet. Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use `DISTINCT 1`? Also, you should be selecting from the product table, and Use a left join to select the corresponding photo.